# Multiple awaits in for loop how to fix?

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await, eslint

I have a for loop with multiple awaits and have no idea how to Promise.all each one so that I can remove the "Unexpected `await` inside a loop" esLint error. I have seen examples of fixes with Promise.all but it is for only 1 await. My loop has 3 awaits. Here is my code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    let b = await http.get(...)
    let c = await http.get(...)
    await doSomethingElse(i, b, c);
}
```

how do I remove all the awaits? without doing so my whole function will fail

Comment: well you're never calling function1 or function2. You only need to await something it it's a Promise

Comment: Can you post your *actual* code? `function` does not look to be a function call, nor `function2`, nor is assignment to `this` permitted, nor is `this` nor `that` used later

Comment: i just changed the functions but basically the http.get returns a number

Comment: You don't appear to be using `b` nor `c` now...

Comment: ok sorry i added the variables to the last await function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `Promise.all`:

- Each iteration of the loop
- The requests for `b` and `c`, because neither is dependent on the other

```
Promise.all(
    a.map(
        (_, i) => Promise.all([
            http.get(...), // gets b
            http.get(...), // gets c
        ])
            .then(([b, c]) => doSomethingElse(i, b, c))
    )
)
    .then(() => {
        // everything is finished
    });
```

Comment: sry I am a bit confused can you not use the for loop here?

Comment: You shouldn't, because then the process will be `O(n)`, depending on how many items are in the original array - the linter is warning you not to wait for each Promise to resolve in serial, and this is the solution to that.